# Degrees Minutes delimited Seconds conversion

Tags: coordinate-system, convert

How do you handle delimited seconds?

I can find a bunch of stuff on converting degrees minutes seconds. That is easy enough. My question is what about when there is a 4th set of numbers for example, 41 39'51.91N, 71 15'00.47W.

What do I do with the 91 or 47?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Degrees, Minutes and Seconds (DMS) examples that you have cited your seconds are presented with a decimal point in them because their measurement and recording has not resulted in a round number.

You would handle them in the same way as DMS values where the seconds are integer numbers. For some purposes you might choose to round them to integers.